# Custom Spring annotation for request parameters - custom resolver never invoked

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-annotations, resolver

I've implemented custom annotation in my project, but implemented method argument resolver was never invoked. 
Can someone help me with this issue?

My implementation:

**Annotation**

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String value();
}
```

**Resolver**

```
public class MyAnnotationResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

   public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
         System.out.println("supportsParameter invoked!");
         return parameter.getParameterAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class) != null;
   }

   public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        ...
        return "someString";
    }
}
```

**Configuaration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc 
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter { 
  ...   
   @Override   
   public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver>  argumentResolvers) {
      argumentResolvers.add(new MyAnnotationResolver());
      System.out.println("Resolver added!");   
   } 
... 
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/project")
public class ProjectController{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value= "/{hashCode}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String index(@MyAnnotation("hashCode") String hashCode, Model model) {
    ...
    System.out.println(hashCode == null ? "HashCode=null" : "HashCode=" + hashCode);
}
```

As output I get:

`Resolver added!`

`HashCode=null`

Why **supportsParameter(...)** was never invoked?

Answer (score 0):

It is not reproducible. `supportsParameter` gets called with the given code.

Since 3 years have passed after you asked, I checked [the code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e0480f75ac4e0367a053eabd3a07c3fa34eccf61/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java#L135) that was used back then when you posted this question. However, the relevant code didn't change that much.

One possible explanation is that there was an argument resolver that supported the parameter, since it doesn't check another when it finds one.